# Drupal table name which has the name of person who last modified the node

Tags: 8, database

Which is the name of the table which has the author / and or last modifier of the nodes I can find in the table node_field_data ? (drupal 8 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tables to get node user information from:

node_field_data has the uid of the creator in it.

node_revision has the last uid to edit a revision of the node.

Note that if you allow revisions, there can be multiple revisions including ones that have been rolled back.  Use the node table's vid to find the current revision.